# Conditional Expectations (Mainly an integral question)

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two Random variables with a standard normal distribution, and the two variables are independent.

Find $E[X_1|X_1>X_2]$

My answer is far.

If we knew $X_2$, then the answer would be: $\frac{\phi(X_2)}{1-\Phi(X_2)}$

But, since we don't know X_2 either I have

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\phi^2(X_2)}{1-\Phi(X_2)}dX_2$

I cannot solve this integral, I've tried Integration by parts, but I get stuck.

Comment: In what sense you 'do not know ' $X_2$? $X_2 \sim N(0,1)$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure understand your comment. I started off assuming both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $N(0,1)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2011019/321264. Also this is just $E[\max(X_1,X_2)]$:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/327245/321264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi$ and $\Phi$ be the pdf and cdf of the standard normal distribution, and for a condition $A$, let $[A]$ be $1$ if $A$ is true and $0$ otherwise.  Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
{\Bbb E}[X_1\mid X_1>X_2]
&=& \frac{{\Bbb E}[X_1 [X_1>X_2]]}{{\Bbb P}[X_1>X_2]}\\
&=& \frac{1}{{\Bbb P}[X_1>X_2]} \int_{x>y} x \phi(x) \phi(y) \, dy\, dx\\
&=& \frac{1}{{\Bbb P}[X_1>X_2]} \int_{\Bbb R} x \phi(x) \left( \int_{y<x} \phi(y) \, dy\right) \, dx\\
&=& \frac{1}{{\Bbb P}[X_1>X_2]} \int_{\Bbb R} x \phi(x) \Phi(x) \, dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since ${\Bbb P}[X_1>X_2]=\frac12$, this equals
$$
2 \int_{\Bbb R} x \phi(x) \Phi(x) \, dx.
$$
You can integrate this by parts by setting $u=\Phi(x)$, $dv=x \phi(x) dx$.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you elaborate on that first step, I don't quite see how you got there?

Comment: I expanded the answer.

Comment: so Integrating by parts, I get $-\Phi(x)*\phi(x)+\int \phi^2(x)dx$, which I get to be 0?

Comment: No, that's not right.  After all, you expect to have ${\Bbb E}[X_1\mid X_1>X_2]>{\Bbb E}[X_1]=0$.

Comment: Correct, sorry made a mistake with the integral $\int \phi^2(x)$.