# Find $E(\max(X,Y))$ for $X$, $Y$ independent standard normal

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $X,Y$ independent random variables with $X,Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Let $Z=\max(X,Y)$.
I already showed that $F_Z$ of $Z$ suffices $F_Z(z)=F(z)^2$.

Now I need to find $EZ$.

Should I start like this ?
$$EZ=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \max(x,y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-1/2x^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-1/2y^2} dxdy$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To go back to $Z$ as a function of $(X,Y)$ once one has determined $F_Z$ is counterproductive. Rather, one could compute the density $f_Z$ as the derivative of $F_Z=\Phi^2$, that is, $f_Z=2\varphi\Phi$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF and its derivative $\varphi$ is the standard normal PDF, and use
$$
\mathbb E(Z)=\int zf_Z(z)\mathrm dz=\int 2z\varphi(z)\Phi(z)\mathrm dz.
$$
Since $z\varphi(z)=-\varphi'(z)$ and $\Phi'=\varphi$, an integration by parts yields
$$
\mathbb E(Z)=\int2\varphi\cdot\varphi=\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\varphi(\sqrt2z)\mathrm dz=\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1{\sqrt2}=\frac1{\sqrt{\pi}}.
$$

Comment: I don't understand how you use integration by parts. I know it as $\int fg' = fg - \int f'g$

Comment: Indeed, try $f=\Phi$ and $g=-2\varphi$.

Comment: Aaah thanks. Another question, if you dont mind. If I would solve it by double integrals, is the double integral I wrote down correct ?

Comment: Kind of the definition, ain't it?

Comment: I'm not sure why $f_{(X,Y)}=f_X \cdot f_Y$

Comment: Independence implies (in fact, is equivalent to) the identity $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

While the OP asks about the case of $X$~N(0,1) and $Y$~N(0,1) independent, ... the more general problem that nests same is of course $(X,Y)$ ~ standardBivariateNormal, with joint pdf $f(x,y)$:

[image]

The general solution to $E[\text{max}(X,Y)]$ ... obtained here using the mathStatica / *Mathematica* combo ... is simply:

[image]

For the special case of independence, $\rho$ = 0, and the solution simplifies to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}$.

Comment: For a mathematical solution to the formula exhibited here, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/382260/).