# Expected value of $\max\{X,Y\}$ when $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, expected-value

> Random vector $(X,Y)\sim N(0,0,1,1,\rho)$, that is to say, the density function of $(X,Y)$ is given by
>   $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(x^2-2\rho xy+y^2)\right\}$$
>   Prove that 
>   $$E\max\{X,Y\}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\rho}{\pi}}.$$

I have trouble evaluating the integral:
$$\iint_{x\ge y}x\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(x^2-2\rho xy+y^2)\right\}dxdy$$
This can be turned into 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left\{-\frac{y^2}{2}\right\}dy\int_{y}^{\infty}x\exp\left\{-\frac{(x-\rho y)^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right\}dx$$
However, when changing variable in the second part, I cannot get rid of the $\rho y \exp\{\cdots\}$and thus got stuck here.

Any hint or solutions are welcomed, thanks!

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of another question already answered: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327245/let-x-y-sim-mathcaln0-1-let-z-maxx-y-find-ez/380270#380270)

Comment: @wolfies Thank you, but here I have an annoying $\rho$, which prevent me from using the similar method.

Comment: The link in wolfies's comment does not lead to a solution but to an answer which merely provides a formula without any mathematical explanation nor any mathematical insight. @wolfies: Why not start actually doing some maths? Imho this would be more fun than stealthily advertising this commercial software of yours.

Comment: @Did lol - if you had some cool computational tools, you could spend more time doing real math, and less time cranking out integrals. Anyway - it's the same question, and you could easily have modified your answer on the linked existing page to provide your explanation for the more general $\rho$ case that I had already derived.

Comment: @wolfies Again? Been through this pseudo-argument already, no? By the way, when do YOU do/explain/present some maths on MSE? Oops... sorry, I forgot that you have a product to sell, no time for the mundane activity called mathematics.

Comment: @wolfies And we DO have "some cool computational tools", thank you, but unlike the one you try to advertise on this site, they are freely available...

Comment: @Did Well you should use them then! I'd love to see what some other tools can do, and you could tighten up your posts to something much more compact, without having to crank out every step and intermediate step manually.

Comment: @wolfies Too cute to be true: with only one comment, you proved that the whole purpose of the site escapes you entirely. Well done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the change of variable $x=z+\rho y$ in the inner integral yields the integral you are after as the sum of two terms.

The inner integral of the first term involves the function $z\mathrm e^{-cz^2/2}$ for some positive $c$, which is easily integrated since it has a primitive proportional to $\mathrm e^{-cz^2/2}$.

The second term is proportional to
$$
\int_\mathbb R\mathrm e^{-y^2/2}\left(\int_{(1-\rho)y}^\infty y\mathrm e^{-cz^2/2}\mathrm dz\right)\mathrm dy=\int_\mathbb R\mathrm e^{-cz^2/2}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{z/(1-\rho)}y\mathrm e^{-y^2/2}\mathrm dy\right)\mathrm dz,
$$
that is,
$$
-\int_\mathbb R\mathrm e^{-cz^2/2}\mathrm e^{-bz^2/2}\mathrm dz,
$$
for some positive $b$. This is the integral of a multiple of a gaussian density, hence has a well known value.

---

An easier road is to note that $2\max(X,Y)=X+Y+|X-Y|$, that $E[X]=E[Y]=0$ and that $X-Y$ is normal centered with variance $\sigma^2=2(1-\rho)$ hence
$$
2E[\max(X,Y)]=E[|X-Y|]=\sigma E[|Z|],
$$
where $Z$ is standard gaussian. A standard computation yields $E[|Z|]=\sqrt{2/\pi}$ hence
$$
E[\max(X,Y)]=\frac{\sigma}2\cdot\sqrt{\frac2\pi}=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{2\pi}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\rho}{\pi}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested further in this topic, there is a published paper by Nadarajah and Kotz that derives the pdf of max$(X,Y)$ as an Azzalini skew-Normal, and derives the expectation etc:

> Nadarajah, S. and Kotz, S. (2008), "Exact Distribution of the Max/Min of Two Gaussian Random Variables", IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON VERY LARGE SCALE INTEGRATION (VLSI) SYSTEMS, VOL. 16, NO. 2, FEBRUARY 2008

Some of these results go back years.

If you are interested in the trivariate case, i.e. the pdf of max$(X,Y,Z)$, when $(X,Y,Z)$ ~ trivariate Normal, there is working paper / presentation available for download on the internet by Balakrishnan ... just google it and you will (hopefully) find it.

> A Skewed Look at Bivariate and Multivariate Order Statistics
>   Prof. N. Balakrishnan
>   Working paper / presentation (2007)