# Expectation of maxiumum of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, expectation

could you help me or give me a hint on how to start with the following:

Let $X,Y$ ~ $N(0,1)$ with correlation $corr(X,Y) = \rho$. It follows that:

$$E[\max(X,Y)] = \sqrt{\frac{1-\rho}{\pi}}$$

How should I start here?

Comment: [Expected value of $\max\{X,Y\}$ when $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382237/expected-value-of-max-x-y-when-x-y-is-bivariate-normal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, re-write the max:
$$\max(X,Y)=\frac{X+Y+|X-Y|}{2}$$
Then,
$$\mathsf E \max(X,Y)=\frac{\mathsf E X+\mathsf E Y+\mathsf E |X-Y|}{2}=\frac{0+0+\mathsf E |X-Y|}{2}$$

Now you have the difference of two Normal variables. Hence, the result is Normal and the mean and variance can be easily calculated.

The absolute value converts a Gaussian RV to a [folded-Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution) RV. Again, the mean is easily derived.

Comment: Very elegant, +1.

Comment: Thanks @Math1000 for your positive comment.