# Expectation of a conditional normal random variable.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y \in \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be independent. Determine $\mathbb{E}Z$ where
$$Z=\begin{cases} X \,& \text{,if } \; X\geq Y \\
0 \,& \text{,if } \; X<Y
\end{cases}
$$
What I thought of is somehow using $\mathbb{E}Z=\mathbb{E}(X \;\vert \; X-Y\geq0)$ (assuming it's correct), however this is where I'm stuck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $E\left[Z\right]=E\left[X\mid X\ge Y\right]P(X\ge Y)$ instead. Several posts on this conditional expectation, like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2011019/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3857155/321264.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, for any measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and random vector $U:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that

$$
\operatorname{E}[f(U)]:=\int_{\Omega }f(U)\,d P=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(u) P_U(du)\tag1
$$

where $P_U:=P\circ U^{-1}$ is the probability measure induced by $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, as $Z=h(X,Y)$ for

$$
h(x,y):=\begin{cases}
x,&\text{ when }x\geqslant y\\
0,& \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

then we have that

$$
\operatorname{E}[Z]=\int_{\Omega }h(X,Y)\,d P=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}h(x,y)P_{X,Y}(dx,dy)\tag3
$$

where $P_{X,Y}$ is the probability measure induced in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the random vector $(X,Y)$.

As $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. standard normal, then $P_{X,Y}=f_{X,Y}\cdot \lambda _2= f_X\cdot f_Y\cdot \lambda _2$, where $\lambda _2$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then (3) becomes

$$
\operatorname{E}[Z]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}h(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y)d(x,y)=\int_{\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geqslant y\}}xf_X(x)f_Y(y)\,d(x,y)\tag4
$$

where the result follows easily using Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Denote $f_{X,Y}$ the join distribution. \begin{align*}
\mathbb E[Z]&=\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_{X\geq Y}]\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R}x\mathbb P\{X\in \,\mathrm d x, \boldsymbol 1_{X\geq Y}=1\}\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R}x\int_{-\infty }^x f_{X,Y}(x,u)\,\mathrm d u\,\mathrm d x.
\end{align*}
Using Fubini allows you to conclude.