# Maximum of two standard normal distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, numerical-methods, normal-distribution, constants

#### 1. Introduction

I want to know how the distribution of the maximum of two independent normal distribution is like.

The background is that I am making AI of some games, and I am trying to do something similar to [Minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax). However, with assumption that the noise of evaluation function is normally distributed, I realized that the algorithm needs to estimate how the maximum of several normal distribution is like.

(There is NO requirement to understand the background like Minimax, for answering this question.)

#### 2. Writing Distribution Mathematically

Let $f_1(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, the probability density function (PDF) of standard normal distribution, and let $\Phi_1(x)$ be the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of it.

Let $f_2(x)$ and $\Phi_2(x)$ be the PDF and CDF of the maximum of two independent standard normal distribution. It is not difficult to see that $\Phi_2(x) = \Phi_1(x)^2$. Therefore,

$$f_2(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \Phi_2(x) = 2 \frac{d\Phi_1(x)}{dx} \Phi_1(x) = 2 f_1(x) \Phi_1(x)$$

We drew a graph at [desmos.com](https://desmos.com) of the PDF and CDF, and it was like the following figure (PDF is red and CDF is blue).

[image: Graph of PDF and CDF]

We can see that the PDF is not symmetric, and is a little bit skewed to the right (positive skew).

#### 3. The average and variance

Using [desmos.com](https://desmos.com), I could obtain the following result:

- The average is $\mu = 0.5641895835\dots$
- The standard deviation is $\sigma = 0.8256452711\dots$

I could understand that $\sigma = \sqrt{1 - \mu^2}$, because one can show that the expected square of variable is exactly $1$.

$$E[\max(x_1, x_2)^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^2 f_2(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^2 f_1(t) \Phi_1(t) dt$$

$$= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^2 e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \left(\int_{-\infty}^t e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}} du\right) dt = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^t t^2 e^{-\frac{t^2 + u^2}{2}} du dt$$

$$= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \int_{-\frac{3}{4} \pi}^{\frac{1}{4} \pi} r^3 \cos^2 \theta \cdot e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} d\theta dr = \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \left(\int_0^{\infty} r^3 e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} dr \right)\left(\int_{-\frac{3}{4} \pi}^{\frac{1}{4} \pi} \cos^2 \theta d\theta \right)$$

$$= \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \left[-(r^2 + 2) e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}\right]_0^{\infty} \cdot \left[\frac{1}{2} (\sin x \cos x + x)\right]_{-\frac{3}{4} \pi}^{\frac{1}{4} \pi} = 1$$

#### 4. Question

However, I don't have clue how to calculate the exact value of $\mu = 0.5641895835 \dots$

I thought that it is a well-known constant because it is a consequence of a simple problem. However, although I searched on the Internet, there did not seem to be any result about it.

So, I would like to know:

1. whether there is a formula of expressing $\mu$, and
2. the way to calculate $\mu$ precisely.

Additionally, I am also thinking about generalizing to arbitrary set of independent normal distributions about the mean/variance of maximum value.

Comment: See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381212/distribution-of-maximum-of-normally-distributed-random-variables)

Comment: @lulu I'm afraid the question you gave in this comment does not help for my question. As information, the formula on PDF/CDF (in the answer you gave) is already written in my question. What I want to know is the mean and variance, not PDF/CDF.

Comment: You can use integration by parts to get $\mu = \int_0^\infty\left[1-\Phi_1(x)^2-\Phi_1(-x)^2\right]dx$. Might simplify from there to a known integral.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/327245/321264

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $X_1, X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be independent. The trick here is to write
$$\max\{X_1,X_2\}=\frac{1}{2}(X_1+X_2+|X_1-X_2|)$$
From the linearity of expectation, we get that
$$\mathbb{E}(\max\{X_1,X_2\})=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(|X_1-X_2|)$$
Remember now that $X_1-X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$. The expectation of the absolute value of a Gaussian with mean $\mu=0$ and variance $\sigma$ comes out to $\sigma \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ so in this case ($\sigma=\sqrt{2}$) we get that
$$\mathbb{E}(\max\{X_1,X_2\})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\approx 0.56418\dots$$
which is what you calculated graphically.

Generalizing to an arbitrary set of independent standard normal distributions seems to be hard, according to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401527/what-is-known-about-the-maximum-of-several-independent-standard-normal-random-va)
MathOverflow question.

Comment: I would think $1/\pi < 0.5$

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks, it was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Wow, a very elegant solution!