# What is the expected value of the max between two Gaussian distribution.

Tags: probability

I have two independent random variables X and Y. Both follow a Gaussian distribution with a mean of 400 and a standard deviation of 30.

I'm doing the following experiment :
1 - I randomly generate a variable X and a variable Y from the distribution. I store the generated values in a table as well as the maximum between the two, the first column of the table contains the value X the second Y and the third the max between the two
2 - I repeat this process 1000 times and at the end I compute the mean and standard deviation of the third column.

I obtain a distribution that looks like a Gaussian distribution with a mean = 430 and a std of 20. It's like the mean becomes equal to the mean of the original two distributions + the original standard deviation. What's the theoretical explanation for the mean value? And what's the theoretical explanation for the standard of deviation.

Comment: What does "the maximum between the two" mean when each takes one value (for example $390$ for $X$ and $420$ for $Y$)

Comment: @Henry it's 420

Comment: So you mean "the maximum of $X$ and $Y$" when you say "the maximum between the two".   Your empirical $430$ looks high: the expectation should be about $400+\frac{30}{\sqrt{\pi}} \approx 416.9$ according to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527964/maximum-of-two-standard-normal-distribution and my simulation.  Similarly your empirical standard deviation looks low.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was look for. Yes you're right in my simulations I was working with 4 variables instead of 2, tried it with two and it works well. Just one question though what formula did you use to find the standard deviation? I couldn't find it in the link.

Comment: I did it empirically, getting a standard deviation of about $24.8$.  More generally, it is well known that the density of the maximum of $n$ iid $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ random variables is $\frac{n}{\sigma} \phi \left( \frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}  \right) \Phi \left( \frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{n-1}$: that is positively skewed and not a normal density

Comment: Adding a bit to the good comment by @Henry, [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298920/mean-and-variance-of-maximum-of-random-variables) has an answer that shows the variance for the maximum of two identical normal rv's. In this case, this leads to $\sigma_{max} = \sqrt{(1-1/\pi)\sigma^2} \approx 24.77$, on point with the simulations.