# $E(X|X>Y)$ for i.i.d normals?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

In Gluts's "Intermediate Probability" one question says "The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $N(0,1)$-distributed. Determine $E(X|X>Y)$."

So it seems like the conditional distribution of both $X$ and $Y$ ought to be:
$$f_{X,Y|X>Y}(x,y)=\frac{f_X(x)f_Y(y)}{1-F(Y)},-\infty<y<x<\infty$$
And then I can integrate $y$ out to get $f_{X|X>Y}$:
$$f_{X|X>Y}=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{f_X(x)f_Y(y)}{1-F(Y)}dy=f_X(x)\ln(1-F(x)),-\infty<x<\infty$$
Which means:
$$E(X|X>Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)\ln(1-F(X))dx$$
And I have no idea how to solve this integral. Is there another way to approach the problem?

Comment: Did you try to use integration by part? since $f_X(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$, then $f'_X(x)=-xf_X(x)$.

Comment: your first equality is not correct, the denominator of the fraction should be  $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$ rather than $1-F_Y(Y)$

Comment: WNG, I was skipping steps and using $1-F_Y(Y)=P(X>Y)$. Is that incorrect?

Comment: This is just $E[\max(X,Y)]$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/327245/321264.

Comment: Good point. In general, does it hold that: $E[\max\{X,Y\}] = E[X|X>Y]P\{X>Y\} + E[Y|Y>X]P\{Y>X\}$, and if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. then $P\{X>Y\}=P\{Y>X\}=1/2$ and $E[X|X>Y]=E[Y|Y>X]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\mathbb{E}[X|X>Y]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X1\{X>Y\}]}{\mathbb{P}\{X>Y\}},
$$
where
$$
\mathbb{E}[X1\{X>Y\}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X1\{X>Y\}\mid Y]] \\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_y^\infty x\phi(x)dx\right)\phi(y)dy \\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\right)\phi(y)dy=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}
$$

and $\mathbb{P}\{X>Y\}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Very nice trick to condition on $Y$ to get the numerator!